# Fatal error: Allowed memory size. help please

Tags: php

### Hello Guys please help me.

Here's my code,

```
Line 1 -    $imagename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
Line 2 -    $source = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
Line 3 -    $target = "images/".$imagename;
Line 4 -    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
Line 5 -
Line 6 -    $imagepath = $imagename;
Line 7 -    $save = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
Line 8 -    $file = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file
Line 9 -
Line 10 -   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file); 
Line 11 -
Line 12 -   $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height) ; 
Line 13 -   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); 
            imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height) ; 

            imagejpeg($tn, $save, 80) ; 

            $save = "thumb_/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
            $file = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

            $modwidth = 130; 

            $diff = $width / $modwidth;

      $modheight = 185; 
      $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
      imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width,     $height) ; 

      imagejpeg($tn, $save, 80) ;
```

**I have error here.**

***Fatal error:*** Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13056 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\MagicLine\admin\cleo\cleo.php on line 13

Comment: The image you are trying to open is too big for your settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise your memory limit in your php.ini file.  The 128MB limit was exhausted when it tried to allocate 13KB more for one of the operations.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

You can set this in run time by using [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Note:  It is typically unusual for a PHP script to utilize 128MB of memory on its own, but it depends on what you are doing.  I don't have experience with these image functions, so you would have to decide if this is normal usage or if you have a memory leak somewhere in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the beginning of your script:

```
$old = ini_get('memory_limit');
```

Then choose from these three options:

1. `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`
2. `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`
3. `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

At the end of your script (**BEFORE `exit;`**) add:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', $old);
```

Now your problem should be solved.